# disk will not mount

Tags: mount, hard-drive

I get the folowing error when I try to mount a drive:

```
Error mounting /dev/sda1 at /media/ubuntu/f2bebb2d-d57d-4c75-b719-cda5a73d8531: Command-line `mount -t "ext4" -o "uhelper=udisks2,nodev,nosuid" "/dev/sda1" "/media/ubuntu/f2bebb2d-d57d-4c75-b719-cda5a73d8531"' exited with non-zero exit status 32: mount: wrong fs type, bad option, bad superblock on /dev/sda1,
      missing codepage or helper program, or other error
      In some cases useful info is found in syslog - try
      dmesg | tail  or so
```

There are two partition on my hard disk. I have tried starting up with the install disk to see if there are any disk repair apps but it seem that there are not.

Comment: Please edit your question and tell us how you try to mount.

Comment: The drive is the main system boot hd. I downloaded the install image and burned it to a dvd and booted of it. In the side bar the drive is listed and I double clicked on it. A few seconds later the error message pops up.

Comment: I have pulled the drive out an put it into an external case and see if I could mount it on my Mac. In the Disk utilities on the Mac it sees the drive but it will not mount the two partitions.

Answer (score 0):

`wrong fs type, bad option, bad superblock on /dev/sda1`

Either you have used the wrong partition or the filesystem is seriously scrambled.

First double check that your intent is really to mount */dev/sda1*.
Look at the output of:

```
parted /dev/sda print
```

If you're sure that it is the right partition, try to do a file system check:

```
e2fsck /dev/sda1
```

If you need further assistance add the output to your question.

Comment: I was able to find the disk app and it shows the two partitions a 1.1 gigs. It is a 320gb drive and it looks like it is not seeing the third filesystem drive.

Comment: how do I do it as a super user form the try now disc. I get a command not found with e2fsck

Comment: The server has been running with no problem. The two partitions are the file system and swap disk. I and see the partitions when I use the disk app on the instal disk running test/try now instead of install. I did come across this page http://superuser.com/questions/278864/cant-mount-hard-drive-ubuntu and it seems like the problem I am having. The only thing get privilege problems when I run off the disc (sudo). How can I do the test as a super user running of the disc.